# What is OPTIONS * in apache logs?

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, apache2

Getting thousands per hour:

```
   1017 "OPTIONS *
```

I've tried to find more about this in Apache docs but could not.

Comment: Please provide a complete log entry. Also try to deduce *when* it appears or *in which circumstances*, e.g. what actions lead to appearance of these log entries?

Answer (score 1):

from [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS),

> The HTTP OPTIONS method requests permitted communication options for a
> given URL or server. A client can specify a URL with this method, or
> an asterisk (*) to refer to the entire server.

Mostly, OPTIONS method is used to check whether to allow or not (CORS)  browser can access to the API URL. In most browsers, if you call with `XMLHttpRequest` to different hostname will call OPTIONS method (Preflighted requests) first before the real HTTP method unless the CORS is cached. So if you want to reduce OPTIONS call just cache it by using `Access-Control-Max-Age` header.

other alternative ways:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/why-is-an-options-request-sent-and-can-i-disable-it